# NotSerializableException when Tomcat startup

Tags: java, tomcat, netbeans

I'm trying to solve this. I'm using NetBeans 8.0 and TomCat 8.0.9, when server start up throws this NSE:

```
11-Sep-2014 00:01:43.578 WARNING [http-apr-8080-exec-191] org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject No puedo serializar atributo de sesión com.sun.faces.application.view.activeViewMaps para sesión 9AA3A199643F6FDA808F5269DDF0EA86
 java.io.NotSerializableException: model.Estado_civil
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor151.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1509)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1777)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor239.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at java.util.LinkedHashMap.internalWriteEntries(LinkedHashMap.java:333)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor239.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1548)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:441)
at java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap.writeObject(Collections.java:2691)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1935.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:988)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1496)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1432)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1178)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject(StandardSession.java:1710)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.writeObjectData(StandardSession.java:1116)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.doUnload(StandardManager.java:401)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.unload(StandardManager.java:320)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stopInternal(StandardManager.java:487)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5397)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3773)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.reload(ManagerServlet.java:984)
at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:345)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:615)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11AprProtocol.java:277)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2381)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2370)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

model.Estado_civil is POJO and isn't referenced. I delete every code could call this POJO I'm using an empty Bean and an empty XHTML.
I undeployed the project from the server using netbeans and clean and built the project again.
I can't understand why throws this exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing an `Object` that doesn't `implement Serializable` in a `HttpSession`:

```
...
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:348)
at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.doWriteObject(StandardSession.java:1710)
...
```

When Tomcat shuts down it attempts to save the session state to a file using the Java Serialization API. When it starts up again it attempts to restore the session state.

From the method name  - `doWriteObject` - I would say it's attempting to *store* something persistently.

In order to disable this feature entirely you need to add:

```
<Manager pathname="" />
```

To your `context.xml`. The `context.xml` is located in `/META-INF/context.xml` and will look something like:

```
<Context>
    <Manager pathname="" />
</Context>
```

For more information consult the [Tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/manager.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Now works, this problem appear and dissappear since a few days. I don't know English very well, but I'm learning meanwhile I can ask if this affects the operation of the application?
PS: I recently web programming in Java, therefore I do not drive even though the issue of the use of resources, only macro mode.

Comment: Disabling persistent session storage will alter the way Tomcat behaves. In simple terms, when I login to your application and establish a session and in the middle of something, you decide to restart Tomcat. Whether my session will be backed up by Tomcat or not is controlled by this particular setting. For a detailed technical description, refer the documentation link given by Boris.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using your `Estado_civil` (not a good name, btw) in you Session and it doesn't implement `Serializable`. Check the `pathname` attribute description [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html#Standard_Implementation) to find out if your Tomcat persists sessions across restarts. If so, you might want to clean them up before restarting (during development that is).